# Restructure an xml document

Tags: c#, xml

here is my structure of xml document,

```
<worldpatentdata>
    <patent-family>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <familymember>.....</familymember>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <familymember>.....</familymember>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        <familymember>.....</familymember>
    </patent-family>
</worldpatentdata>
```

In the above xml structure,all the `<exchange-documents>` element is found to be child node of `<patent-family>` element.
I want these `<exchange-documents>` elements as childnode of `<family-member>` element,so that the xml have the following structure,

```
<worldpatentdata>
    <patent-family>
        <familymember>.....
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        </familymember>
        <familymember>.....
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        </familymember>
        <familymember>.....
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
            <exchange-documents>......</exchange-documents>
        </familymember>
    </patent-family>
</worldpatentdata>
```

can anybody help me on this?
thanks

Comment: These dotted lines are the structure or you forgot to add xml?

Comment: Okay, we know (now, lol) what it should look like, but you don't give any information about how you're making these xml documents.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of things for you. For future reference, please (please!) indent xml according to its structure. It makes a huge difference to readability. Secondly, always surround inline xml in back-quotes, so it doesn't vanish from sight.

Comment: How would you know, which `<exchange-document>` belongs to which `<familymember>`?

Comment: For your ease with code, highlight the code an press Ctrl+K, it would format the code.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the children of `<patent-family>` via the DOM, remembering every `<exchange-documents>` you encounter along the way. Whenever you see a `<familymember>`, move the remembered elements under it.

Answer (score 0):

Above the top of my head, one way could be to:

1. Use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) to load the xml, and create a tempXDocument.
2. `foreach (XElement...` through the elements and add to XmlNodeList items which are `<exchange-documents>`
3. Add `<familymember>` in tempXDocument when `<familymember>` is found; and add the XmlNodeList to tempXDocument.
4. Save the tempXDocument.